# Themeing ListView

Tags: wpf, themes

From what I understand, ListView has 2 themeing styles, one that it uses when you don't specify a View and one it uses when you do.

```
 <HeaderedContentControl Header="No GridView" Margin="10">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>B</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </HeaderedContentControl>

    <HeaderedContentControl Header="GridView"
                            Margin="10">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Content" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>B</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
```

[image]

How do I style these? .. for example if I was making a custom theme?

I thought I would take a look at an existing theme, so I've downloaded the Luna theme from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972127(v=VS.90).aspx and added it as a resource. (I've added a button so you can see it is indeed using the luna theme)

[image]

But you'll notice that the Listview, other than the column header bit is the same. So it appears that the GridView styling in the luna theme isn't even used? I can go in and change the GridViewItemContainerStyleKey and it has no affect. It always appears to use the aero style

For reference, here is the GridView styling taken from the Luna theme :

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
            Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Border Name="Bd"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewItemContainerStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border Name="Bd"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                       Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dump the complete control template out using Expression Blend. The ones on MSDN aren't the real ones.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem dump GridViewItemContainerStyleKey

Comment: You can, but you have to think outside the box a little bit :). Dump out the style for a GridViewColumnHeader control. You'll see there is quite a bit to it, including the drag and drop roles. Thats what the header is, a GridViewHeaderRowPresenter that is a collection of GridViewColumnHeaders. Just hand edit an empty XAML to put a Grid \ GridViewColumnHeader and it'll let you dump out the template.

Comment: But I'm looking for the style used with GridViewItemContainerStyleKey, not GridViewColumnHeader. Could you tell me the steps I need to take as I'm not the most familiar with Blend

Comment: You want to style the header control items, right? I.e. the thing that says "Content"?

Comment: Nope, I want to style the rows of the ListView (the things that display as 'A'  or 'B' in my question). Which from my understanding, means I need two styles, the normal ListViewItem style (which is used without a gridview), and also, another style for ListViewItem but with x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewItemContainerStyleKey}" (which is used when there is a gridview). It is the latter that I can't get Blend to dump. When I just create it manually (like I showed in my question), it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The header control items are GridiewColumnHeader controls. So you just target them as you normally would:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This will turn your header red. If you want to dump out the real "runtime" template in Blend...

1) go into the XAML

2) update client XAML to:

```
<Grid>
  <GridViewColumnHeader />
</Grid>
```

3) View | Objects & Timelines

4) You should see your window hierarchy there...

```
Window
 Grid
  GridViewColumnHeader
```

5) Select GridViewColumnHeader

6) Right click | Edit Template | Edit A Copy | OK

Then just modify / clean it up / refactor as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Oooooooooooohhh... that is a ListViewItem. The GridView items are the column headers. What I did for that was have a "main" ListViewItem style and use a trigger that points to the ListView.View and if its x:Null, I assume its the normal view and set the template to my normal view template, otherwise set it to my GridView template. I do the same thing for having a themed and non themed version. So I actually have 4 templates.